# What files (PIA) are required for MS Word integration

Tags: c#, .net, office-interop

I am adding MS Word in my C# application as below:

```
Object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application appWord = 
     new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
Document wordDocument = appWord.Documents.Open(docFile, oMissing, false, 
     oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, 
     oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing);
```

Can you tell me what files to export along with the compiled exe, assuming that the client has .NET 2.0 and MS Word installed and not Visual Studio?

I reference this file:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Visual Studio
>   Tools for Office\PIA\Office14\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll

But what if client has Office 13 or 12 or any lower version? Will lower version of MS Word work with this dll and exe? If not then how do I check before calling its code so that the exe does not crash because of any un-managed exception?

Comment: Some info (not exact answer) available at [Office PIA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Microsoft's attention to backwards-compatibility is legendary.  But this works only one way, they don't have a time-machine to know what features they are going to add to the next version.  If you want to promise compatibility with an old Office version then you must use the appropriate PIA to build against.  Testing is required, and you need to be able to provide support if a customer with an old version asks for help, you can get old Office versions through an MSDN subscription.